# “Error getting Mms Carrier values” when querying Android Telephony.Carriers public class

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mms, apn

I am having trouble obtaining the "server", "mms_proxy", and "mms_port". I haven't found anything official anywhere from Google about why this is? I would assume if this is something I cannot do then that would be stated by Google.

The Android developer website shows the Telephony.Carriers class and all that is available but says nothing about restrictions of any kind so at this point I believe it is fair to assume I can access these rather than have to ask the user to find the APN values manually which will make many people give up instantly and not use my App.

Can we please try to find an official answer as to what is going on here, I have attempted to get this information in many ways all leading to very confusing errors that seemingly cannot be explained.

I am running Android 6.01 on the device ZTE Axon 7. The lowest api that my App will allow is api_21 and the Telephony.Carriers class in available from api_19 and up.

I have declared all then necessary permission in the Manifest file and since I am currently testing on sdk "M" (Android 6), I have also acquired the permissions explicitly at Runtime from the user.

This is the code inside my Activity that I run and receive a an error stating "Error getting Mms Carrier values"...this is the whole problem and where I have become stuck.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    int index_ID;

    final String[] PROJECT =
            {
                    Telephony.Carriers.TYPE,
                    Telephony.Carriers.MMSC,
                    Telephony.Carriers.MMSPROXY,
                    Telephony.Carriers.MMSPORT,
            };


    grantMyUriPermission(activity, Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    grantMyUriPermission(activity, Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    Cursor carriers_cursor = SqliteWrapper.query(activity, contentResolver,
            Uri.withAppendedPath(Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"), PROJECT, null, null, null);

    if (carriers_cursor != null)
    {
        /*This crap below isn't needed for this situation but helps avoid ERROR*/
        index_ID = carriers_cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers._ID);
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (index_ID < 0 || !carriers_cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error getting Mms Carrier values");
            carriers_cursor.close();
            return;
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        do
        {
            //Confirm cursor has value assigned to it
            Log.i(TAG, "cursor: "+ carriers_cursor);

            //Get the available columns names
            for (String item : carriers_cursor.getColumnNames())
            {
                //Name of each column available with Cursor
                Log.i(TAG, "item: " + item);

                //Attempt to get String value for each available column
                try
                {
                    //Use the name of the column, to get the index, to get the String value
                    Log.i(TAG, "getString(): " + carriers_cursor.getString(carriers_cursor.getColumnIndex(item)));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
                }
            }
        }
        while (carriers_cursor.moveToNext());

        carriers_cursor.close();

    }
```

The Log output is:

I/SmsReceiveIntentService: Running grantMyUriPermission()

I/SmsReceiveIntentService: Running grantMyUriPermission()

I/NewConversationActivity: Error getting Mms Carrier values

And that's it! Nothing else to go on...?

Comment: There is no `_ID` column in your projection, so `getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers._ID)` will return `-1`, which leads to your error `Log`. Furthermore, AFAIK, there are only about five columns you can get from that Provider unless your app holds the `WRITE_APN_SETTINGS` (which isn't for use by third-party apps), and `_ID` isn't one of them, for whatever reason. I believe the only ones you can get are `APN`, `MMSC`, `MMSPORT`, `MMSPROXY`, and `TYPE`. Trying to query for any others will throw a `SecurityException`.

Comment: Ugh obviously my bad  I copied code from where I was querying other things which had _IDs. I will correct the code and run again and post what happens. But thank you for the other valuable info. All I need is those values few columns so I can send an Mms via data-connection and not the cellular network. I am not sure why anybody would need anything else besides those few columns, but maybe I'll find out one day